# How to start loading a WebView after the view is rendered?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react-native, and am trying to make a component that swipes through 3 WebViews (using react-native-swiper, and the swiper contains 3 WebViews), each of which have animations. The code is something like this -

```
<Swiper autoplay={true} loop={false} >                
    <View style={this.styles.slide1}>
        <WebView source = {require(‘./Page1.html')} />
    </View>
    <View style={this.styles.slide2}>
        <WebView source = {require(‘./Page2.html')}/>
    </View>
    <View style={this.styles.slide3}>
        <WebView source = {require(‘./Page3.html’)}/>
    </View>
</Swiper>
```

The first WebView works fine, but by the time the subsequent WebViews are displayed, their animations are already completed since they have finished loading while the first WebView was still being displayed. Is there any way to delay the URL from loading until the Swiper is ready to display it on screen?

Answer (score 0):

for example :

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shouldShowWebView: false
    };
  }

componentDidMount(){
this.setState({shouldShowWebView: true})
}

render(){
return(
<View>{this.state.shouldShowWebView ? <WebView /> : <View />}</View>
);
}
```

set the initial value of `shouldShowWebView` to `false`. whenever you want to show it, set the value to `true`. for example in `componentDidMount`.  and in render check if it's value is `true` or not. (conditional rendering)
Hope this will help.